# Smart Info Window and Google Maps Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to implement the 'Smart Info Window' code by Pamela Fox into my Google map and I just can't seem to get this to work. The map appears with the markers correctly positioned on it. But when I click on the marker nothing happens, but I don't get any error messages and I must admit to being a bit lost with this.

Where am I going wrong?

**HTML Form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smartinfowindow.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            0: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            1: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:6, 
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
            }); 

            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
         var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var locationname = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var totalfinds = markers[i].getAttribute("totalfinds");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon")));
            var html = locationname + "<p>" + 'No. of finds: ' + "<b>" + totalfinds + "</b>" + "</p>";
            var icon = {}; 
            if (totalfinds == 0) {   
            icon = customIcons[0]; 
            } else if (totalfinds >= 1) {   
            icon = customIcons[1];      
            } 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: address,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
            }); 
          bounds.extend(point);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            google.maps.event.addListener(point, 'click', function(e) {  
          var infobox = new SmartInfoWindow({position: point, map: map, html: html});  
          }); 
            } 
            }); 
            } 

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
            </head>    
            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

**Smart Window JS**

```
/* An SmartInfoWindow is like an info window, but it displays 
* under the marker, opens quicker, and has flexible styling. 
* @param {Object} opts Passes configuration options. 
*/ 
function SmartInfoWindow(opts) { 
google.maps.OverlayView.call(this); 
this.latlng_ = opts.position; 
this.content_ = opts.content; 
this.map_ = opts.map; 
this.height_ = 351; 
this.width_ = 280; 
this.size_ = new google.maps.Size(this.height_, this.width_); 
this.offsetVertical_ = -this.height_; 
this.offsetHorizontal_ = 0; 
this.panned_ = false; 
this.setMap(this.map_); 

// We need to listen to bounds_changed event so that we can redraw 
// absolute position every time the map moves. 
// This is only needed because we append to body instead of map panes. 
var me = this; 
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, 'bounds_changed', function() { 
me.draw(); 
}); 
} 

/** 
* SmartInfoWindow extends GOverlay class from the Google Maps API 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView(); 

/** 
* Creates the DIV representing this SmartInfoWindow 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype.onRemove = function() { 
if (this.div_) { 
this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_); 
this.div_ = null; 
} 
}; 

/** 
* Called when the overlay is first added to the map. 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype.onAdd = function() { 
// Creates the element if it doesn't exist already. 
this.createElement(); 
}; 

/** 
* Redraw based on the current projection and zoom level. 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype.draw = function() { 
// Since we use bounds changed listener, projection is sometimes null 
if (!this.getProjection()) { 
return; 
} 

// This gives us the position in the tiles div. 
var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_); 
var centerPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.map_.getCenter()); 
var centerPositionReal = new google.maps.Point(this.map_.getDiv().offsetWidth/2, this.map_.getDiv().offsetHeight/2); 
// Figure out difference between map div and tiles div, so that we can 
// calculate position in map div 
var centerOffsetX = -centerPosition.x + centerPositionReal.x; 
var centerOffsetY = -centerPosition.y + centerPositionReal.y; 

if (!pixPosition) return; 
var alignment = this.getBestAlignment(); 
var paddingTop = 0; 
var paddingLeft = 0; 
var widthLess = 0; 
switch (alignment) { 
case SmartInfoWindow.Align.ABOVE: 
this.width_ = 280; 
this.height_ = 351; 
image = 'infobox_above.gif'; 
this.offsetX_ = -(this.width_ / 2 - 17); 
this.offsetY_ = -(this.height_ + 12); 
break; 
case SmartInfoWindow.Align.BELOW: 
this.width_ = 280; 
this.height_ = 351; 
image = 'infobox_below.gif'; 
this.offsetX_ = -(this.width_ / 2 - 17); 
this.offsetY_ = -15; 
paddingTop = 20; 
break; 
case SmartInfoWindow.Align.LEFT: 
this.width_ = 307; 
this.height_ = 326; 
image = 'infobox_left.gif'; 
this.offsetX_ = -(this.width_) + 10; 
this.offsetY_ = -(this.height_ / 2 + 33); 
widthLess = 20; 
break; 
case SmartInfoWindow.Align.RIGHT: 
image = 'infobox_right.gif'; 
this.width_ = 307; 
this.height_ = 326; 
this.offsetX_ = 6; 
this.offsetY_ = -(this.height_ / 2 + 33); 
paddingLeft = 20; 
widthLess = 20; 
break; 
} 
// Now position our DIV based on the DIV coordinates of our bounds 
this.div_.style.width = this.width_ + 'px'; 
this.div_.style.left = (pixPosition.x + this.offsetX_) + centerOffsetX + 'px'; 
this.div_.style.height = this.height_ + 'px'; 
this.div_.style.top = (pixPosition.y + this.offsetY_) + centerOffsetY + 'px'; 
//this.div_.style.paddingTop = paddingTop + 'px'; 
//this.div_.style.paddingLeft = paddingLeft + 'px'; 
this.div_.style.background = 'url("images/' + image + '")'; 
this.div_.style.display = 'block'; 

this.wrapperDiv_.style.width = (this.width_- widthLess) + 'px'; 
this.wrapperDiv_.style.height = this.height_ + 'px'; 
this.wrapperDiv_.style.marginTop = paddingTop + 'px'; 
this.wrapperDiv_.style.marginLeft = paddingLeft + 'px'; 
this.wrapperDiv_.style.overflow = 'hidden'; 
if (!this.panned_) { 
this.panned_ = true; 
this.maybePanMap(); 
} 
}; 

/** 
* Creates the DIV representing this SmartInfoWindow in the floatPane. If the panes 
* object, retrieved by calling getPanes, is null, remove the element from the 
* DOM. If the div exists, but its parent is not the floatPane, move the div 
* to the new pane. 
* Called from within draw. Alternatively, this can be called specifically on 
* a panes_changed event. 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype.createElement = function() { 
var panes = this.getPanes(); 
var div = this.div_; 
if (!div) { 
// This does not handle changing panes. You can set the map to be null and 
// then reset the map to move the div. 
div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div'); 
div.style.border = '0px none'; 
div.style.position = 'absolute'; 
div.style.overflow = 'hidden'; 
var wrapperDiv = this.wrapperDiv_ = document.createElement('div'); 
var contentDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
if (typeof this.content_ == 'string') { 
contentDiv.innerHTML = this.content_; 
} else { 
contentDiv.appendChild(this.content_); 
} 

var topDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
topDiv.style.textAlign = 'right'; 
var closeImg = document.createElement('img'); 
closeImg.src = 'images/closebigger.gif'; 
closeImg.style.width = '32px'; 
closeImg.style.height = '32px'; 
closeImg.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
topDiv.appendChild(closeImg); 

function removeSmartInfoWindow(ib) { 
return function() { 
ib.setMap(null); 
}; 
} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeImg, 'click', removeSmartInfoWindow(this)); 

wrapperDiv.appendChild(topDiv); 
wrapperDiv.appendChild(contentDiv); 
div.appendChild(wrapperDiv); 
div.style.display = 'none'; 
// Append to body, to avoid bug with Webkit browsers 
// attempting CSS transforms on IFRAME or SWF objects 
// and rendering badly. 
document.body.appendChild(div); 
} else if (div.parentNode != panes.floatPane) { 
// The panes have changed. Move the div. 
div.parentNode.removeChild(div); 
panes.floatPane.appendChild(div); 
} else { 
// The panes have not changed, so no need to create or move the div. 
} 
}; 

SmartInfoWindow.mouseFilter = function(e) { 
e.returnValue = 'true'; 
e['handled'] = true; 
} 

/** 
* Closes infowindow 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype.close = function() { 
this.setMap(null); 
}; 

/** 
* Pan the map to fit the SmartInfoWindow, 
* if its top or bottom corners aren't visible. 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype.maybePanMap = function() { 
// if we go beyond map, pan map 
var map = this.map_; 
var projection = this.getProjection(); 
var bounds = map.getBounds(); 
if (!bounds) return; 

// The dimension of the infowindow 
var iwWidth = this.width_; 
var iwHeight = this.height_; 

// The offset position of the infowindow 
var iwOffsetX = this.offsetX_; 
var iwOffsetY = this.offsetY_; 

var anchorPixel = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_); 
var bl = new google.maps.Point(anchorPixel.x + iwOffsetX + 20, 
anchorPixel.y + iwOffsetY + iwHeight); 
var tr = new google.maps.Point(anchorPixel.x + iwOffsetX + iwWidth, 
anchorPixel.y + iwOffsetY); 
var sw = projection.fromDivPixelToLatLng(bl); 
var ne = projection.fromDivPixelToLatLng(tr); 

// The bounds of the infowindow 
if (!map.getBounds().contains(ne) || !map.getBounds().contains(sw)) { 
map.panToBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne)); 
} 
}; 

/** 
* @enum {number} 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.Align = { 
ABOVE: 0, 
LEFT: 1, 
RIGHT: 2, 
BELOW: 3 
}; 

/** 
* Finds best alignment for infowindow. 
* @return {number} Alignment. 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype.getBestAlignment = function() { 
var bestAlignment = SmartInfoWindow.Align.LEFT; 
var minPan = 0; 

for (var alignment in SmartInfoWindow.Align) { 
var alignment = SmartInfoWindow.Align[alignment]; 
var panValue = this.getPanValue(alignment); 
if (panValue > minPan) { 
minPan = panValue; 
bestAlignment = alignment; 
} 
} 

return bestAlignment; 
}; 

/** 
* Calculates distance of corner for each alignment. 
* @param {number} alignment An alignment constant. 
* @return {number} Distance for that alignment. 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.prototype.getPanValue = function(alignment) { 
var mapSize = new google.maps.Size(this.map_.getDiv().offsetWidth, 
this.map_.getDiv().offsetHeight); 
var bounds = this.map_.getBounds(); 
var sideLatLng; 
switch (alignment) { 
case SmartInfoWindow.Align.ABOVE: 
sideLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), 
this.latlng_.lng()); 
break; 
case SmartInfoWindow.Align.BELOW: 
sideLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), 
this.latlng_.lng()); 
break; 
case SmartInfoWindow.Align.RIGHT: 
sideLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latlng_.lat(), 
bounds.getNorthEast().lng()); 
break; 
case SmartInfoWindow.Align.LEFT: 
sideLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latlng_.lat(), 
bounds.getSouthWest().lng()); 
break; 
} 
var dist = SmartInfoWindow.distHaversine(this.latlng_.lat(), this.latlng_.lng(), 
sideLatLng.lat(), sideLatLng.lng()); 
return dist; 
}; 


/** 
* Converts degrees to radians. 
* @param {number} num Angle in degrees. 
* @return {number} Angle in radians. 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.toRad = function(num) { 
return num * Math.PI / 180; 
} 

/** 
* Calculates distance between two coordinates. 
* @param {number} lat1 Latitude of first coord. 
* @param {number} lon1 Longitude of second coord. 
* @param {number} lat2 Latitude of second coord. 
* @param {number} lon2 Longitude of second coord. 
* @return {number} The distance. 
*/ 
SmartInfoWindow.distHaversine = function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) { 
var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km 
var dLat = SmartInfoWindow.toRad(lat2 - lat1); 
var dLon = SmartInfoWindow.toRad(lon2 - lon1); 
lat1 = SmartInfoWindow.toRad(lat1), lat2 = SmartInfoWindow.toRad(lat2); 

var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + 
Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * 
Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)); 
var d = R * c; 
return d; 
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function InfoBox(opts) {
  google.maps.OverlayView.call(this);
  this.latlng_ = opts.latlng;
  this.map_ = opts.map;
  this.offsetVertical_ = -195;
  this.offsetHorizontal_ = 0;
  this.height_ = 165;
  this.width_ = 266;

  var me = this;
  this.boundsChangedListener_ =
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, "bounds_changed", function() {
      return me.panMap.apply(me);
    });

  // Once the properties of this OverlayView are initialized, set its map so
  // that we can display it.  This will trigger calls to panes_changed and
  // draw.
  this.setMap(this.map_);
}

/* InfoBox extends GOverlay class from the Google Maps API
 */
InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

/* Creates the DIV representing this InfoBox
 */
InfoBox.prototype.remove = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
  }
};

/* Redraw the Bar based on the current projection and zoom level
 */
InfoBox.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Creates the element if it doesn't exist already.
  this.createElement();
  if (!this.div_) return;

  // Calculate the DIV coordinates of two opposite corners of our bounds to
  // get the size and position of our Bar
  var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
  if (!pixPosition) return;

  // Now position our DIV based on the DIV coordinates of our bounds
  this.div_.style.width = this.width_ + "px";
  this.div_.style.left = (pixPosition.x + this.offsetHorizontal_) + "px";
  this.div_.style.height = this.height_ + "px";
  this.div_.style.top = (pixPosition.y + this.offsetVertical_) + "px";
  this.div_.style.display = 'block';
};

/* Creates the DIV representing this InfoBox in the floatPane.  If the panes
 * object, retrieved by calling getPanes, is null, remove the element from the
 * DOM.  If the div exists, but its parent is not the floatPane, move the div
 * to the new pane.
 * Called from within draw.  Alternatively, this can be called specifically on
 * a panes_changed event.
 */
InfoBox.prototype.createElement = function() {
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  var div = this.div_;
  if (!div) {
    // This does not handle changing panes.  You can set the map to be null and
    // then reset the map to move the div.
    div = this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.border = "0px none";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.background = "url('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/blueinfowindow.gif')";
    div.style.width = this.width_ + "px";
    div.style.height = this.height_ + "px";
    var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
    contentDiv.style.padding = "30px"
    contentDiv.innerHTML = "<b>Hello World!</b>";

    var topDiv = document.createElement("div");
    topDiv.style.textAlign = "right";
    var closeImg = document.createElement("img");
    closeImg.style.width = "32px";
    closeImg.style.height = "32px";
    closeImg.style.cursor = "pointer";
    closeImg.src = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/closebigger.gif";
    topDiv.appendChild(closeImg);

    function removeInfoBox(ib) {
      return function() {
        ib.setMap(null);
      };
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeImg, 'click', removeInfoBox(this));

    div.appendChild(topDiv);
    div.appendChild(contentDiv);
    div.style.display = 'none';
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
    this.panMap();
  } else if (div.parentNode != panes.floatPane) {
    // The panes have changed.  Move the div.
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
  } else {

    // The panes have not changed, so no need to create or move the div.
  }
}

/* Pan the map to fit the InfoBox.
 */
InfoBox.prototype.panMap = function() {
  // if we go beyond map, pan map
  var map = this.map_;
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  if (!bounds) return;

  // The position of the infowindow
  var position = this.latlng_;

  // The dimension of the infowindow
  var iwWidth = this.width_;
  var iwHeight = this.height_;

  // The offset position of the infowindow
  var iwOffsetX = this.offsetHorizontal_;
  var iwOffsetY = this.offsetVertical_;

  // Padding on the infowindow
  var padX = 40;
  var padY = 40;

  // The degrees per pixel
  var mapDiv = map.getDiv();
  var mapWidth = mapDiv.offsetWidth;
  var mapHeight = mapDiv.offsetHeight;
  var boundsSpan = bounds.toSpan();
  var longSpan = boundsSpan.lng();
  var latSpan = boundsSpan.lat();
  var degPixelX = longSpan / mapWidth;
  var degPixelY = latSpan / mapHeight;

  // The bounds of the map
  var mapWestLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
  var mapEastLng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
  var mapNorthLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var mapSouthLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();

  // The bounds of the infowindow
  var iwWestLng = position.lng() + (iwOffsetX - padX) * degPixelX;
  var iwEastLng = position.lng() + (iwOffsetX + iwWidth + padX) * degPixelX;
  var iwNorthLat = position.lat() - (iwOffsetY - padY) * degPixelY;
  var iwSouthLat = position.lat() - (iwOffsetY + iwHeight + padY) * degPixelY;

  // calculate center shift
  var shiftLng =
      (iwWestLng < mapWestLng ? mapWestLng - iwWestLng : 0) +
      (iwEastLng > mapEastLng ? mapEastLng - iwEastLng : 0);
  var shiftLat =
      (iwNorthLat > mapNorthLat ? mapNorthLat - iwNorthLat : 0) +
      (iwSouthLat < mapSouthLat ? mapSouthLat - iwSouthLat : 0);

  // The center of the map
  var center = map.getCenter();

  // The new map center
  var centerX = center.lng() - shiftLng;
  var centerY = center.lat() - shiftLat;

  // center the map to the new shifted center
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(centerY, centerX));

  // Remove the listener after panning is complete.
  google.maps.event.removeListener(this.boundsChangedListener_);
  this.boundsChangedListener_ = null;
};
</script>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            0: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            1: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:6, 
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
            }); 

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var locationname = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var totalfinds = markers[i].getAttribute("totalfinds");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon")));
            var html = locationname + "<p>" + 'No. of finds: ' + "<b>" + totalfinds + "</b>" + "</p>";
            var icon = {}; 
            if (totalfinds == 0) {   
            icon = customIcons[0]; 
            } else if (totalfinds >= 1) {   
            icon = customIcons[1];      
            } 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: address,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow

            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            var infoBox = new InfoBox({latlng: marker.getPosition(), map: map});
            });

            bounds.extend(point);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            } 
            }); 
            } 

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
            </head>    
            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your code correctly you assign listener to point (google.maps.LatLng), while you should do it for a marker. In fragment:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(point, 'click', function(e) {  
      var infobox = new SmartInfoWindow({position: point, map: map, html: html});  
      });
```

change point to marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {  
      var infobox = new SmartInfoWindow({position: point, map: map, html: html});  
      });
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post, it's appreciated. I've changed the coding as you suggested but I'm now getting the following error when I click on the marker: Message: Type mismatch. Line: 151 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI: http://websitename/js/SmartInfoWindow.js
I've been through the Javascript & I can't find any differences in terms of spelling between that & my HTML file. I've also checked that the paths for the files are coorect & nothing seems to be amiss there. Could you tell me please have you any ideas as to what the problem may be? Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: I am not so sure if this is the case, but in this smart info window constructor I see assignment to window content (this.content_ = opts.content; - I believe this is what you want to pass in 3rd argument of your call) from field named content not html as you entered. My guess would be to change:

     var infobox = new SmartInfoWindow({position: point, map: map, html: html});  

into:

    var infobox = new SmartInfoWindow({position: point, map: map, content: html});  

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, sincere thanks for helping me out on this. I've been back to the coding & demo on the Google site at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html?r=63 If you look at the demo it does say that the content, as you quite rightly said is my html equivalet. I've changed the code as you suggested & I've also changed 'var html' in my code to match the demo. The code works to a degree but the frame & the close button don't render properly & the Info window is off the map i.e. not connected to the marker. Have you any ideas please? Regards chris

Comment: I don't see anything wrong about this code right now, would you please give a link to the page so I could examine it more closely?

Comment: Not sure if it will work but please try pass marker.getPosition() instead of point in SmartInfoWindow constructor: 
var infobox = new SmartInfoWindow({position: marker.getPosition(), map: map, content: html}); 
or alternatively e.latLng: 
var infobox = new SmartInfoWindow({position: e.latLng, map: map, content: html});

Comment: Hi, firstly many thanks for your continuing help. I've tried both suggestions and unfortunately neither work. The latter i.e. e.latLng... didn't render the map or the markers. The results of your first suggestion will similar to what I had before. The contents of the InfoWindow show on screen, but they are not attached to the marker and the actual design of the bubble and close 'x' don't render at all. I've tried adding a location.lat and location.lng to try an mirror the demo html page, but I couldn't get that to work either. It's proving to be a little difficult! Kind regards Chris.

Comment: Hi, I'm very conscious that I'm taking up a lot of your time with this & I think the problem is that my coding doesn't include all the parameters needed. I hope you don't mind, but I've been lookimg at some other code for the custom Infowindow, which I think I can amend to suit my needs. I am however having some issues. I just wondered whether it was possible please that you could take a look at this. I get the InfoWindow to appear, but not next to each marker I have to close one window before I can open another. I've added an update to my original post. Sincere thanks and kind regards Chris.

Comment: What I actually meant in my previous comment was {position: this.getPosition(), map: map, content: html} instead of marker.getPosition(), sorry for the mistake. In this new circumstances I am not sure what the problem looks like exactly, so a link would be helpful. What's more, do you intend to open multiple infoboxes at once? You could attach the box to the marker: marker.infoBox = ... instead of var infoBox so you could maintain control over them (that is generally a good idea). Or if you want only one box, declare it along with the map (in larger scope) and close and reopen in eventhandler.

Comment: Hi please find attached the link to my webpage. http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/alllocationssmart.html. In terms of how I would like it to behave. I'd like to be able to click on Marker A for example, the map to pan & centre on the marker & the InfoWindow to appear. If the user then clicks on Marker B, the Infowindow disappears from Marker A & the map then pans & centers on Marker B with the InfoWindow open. I've been working on this myself, trying to change & in some cases replace areas of the but without any luck. Once again, sincere thanks your time, trouble & patience.  Kind regards. Chris

Comment: link you have provided seems to be pointing to previous version (same not rendering box and linking to js/SmartInfoWindow.js in source). Nevertheless I would recommend declaring infoBox globally so that you could close it right before opening new one 

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
    removeInfoBox(infoBox); //not sure if correct call but you know what I mean
    infoBox = new InfoBox({latlng: this.getPosition(), map: map});
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    });

I have also included a line panning center to marker location. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the incorrect link, this is the correct one http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/alllocationsinfowindow. I know that I'm missing something here, probably a real beginners mistake, but I've tried your code and I get an error of 'Objected expected - line 241'. I'm really sorry to be a pain with this. Am I right in thinking it's lookimg for the InfoBox? Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: right, before first initialization it is undefined or null (whatever), add standard null check:
if (InfoBox) removeInfoBox(InfoBox);

Comment: Hi, I've managed to get the window to work using the following: google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) { removeInfoBox(infoBox);   
var infoBox = new InfoBox({latlng: this.getPosition(), map: map});      
}); 

The only thing I can't get to work is that the Window doesn't move to each marker when clicked, i.e. each marker opens up it's own Window, but I'll do some more work to try and rectify this. I just want to say many thnaks for all the time and trouble you've put itno this for me, it is greatly appreciated. Kind regards. Chris.